# process.waitforexit hangs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, process

Dont mark downvote untill you dont read it fully.
however many questions exists by same heading, none of them is working, and i want to solve my specific problem. Please help.

I am working on C#4.0 Asp.Net application,
On a web page on button click i want to create an exe.
So that i am using **devenv.exe**, but it hangs on **process.waitforexit** command.

This was working, for more then 7 monnths, but before two days suddenly it stoped working.
It is also working on localhost, after publishing on server it is not working.
The code is below

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"D:\ProjFolder\xxx.sln /rebuild";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

OutputMsg = "";

if (!process.Start())
{
    OutputMsg = "failed.</br>";
    OutputMsg += process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(OutputMsg);
    return false;
}
// Some people said that this is buffer problem, you should release it by reading
// output, i used "ReadToEnd" that is not working, so trying this again, and also it
// is not working
//while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
//{
//string outputmsg = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
//HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(outputmsg);
//}
//string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit(60000);
if (process.HasExited)
{
    OutputMsg = "Succeeded.";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(OutputMsg);
}
else
{
    OutputMsg = "Process not completed properly.";
    process.Kill();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(OutputMsg);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but maybe your actual project path contains spaces in its name?

Comment: "Dont mark downvote untill you dont read it fully" - are you sure that's how you want people to act? I think you've got one too many negatives in there.

Comment: Also, I'm almost certain you're not meant to run visual studio on a web server. Any reason you used VS and not just the MSBUILD infrastructure?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever by using this way "devenv.exe" it dont opens the VS, it compiles the solution and produce the exe, although we can use MSBuild also.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it was mentioned, because some the heading seems it is duplicate question

Comment: Yes, but what you've actually said is the equivalent to "if you've *not* read this question fully, then you can downvote"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever please dont discuss the language about. Please discuss if you have any suggestion regarding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, I tried **MSBuild.Exe**, and it is worked well.
Still now, it is not recognised why devenv.exe stoped working.

However msbuild.exe is working well.

Note: MSBuild.exe can be used through command prompt and for complie a project by coding, we can use this, command line utility.

msbuild.exe located in following locations, be care full regarding version

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

target project/solution framework version and msbuild.exe version should be same.

if someone need help about msbuild.exe this link may be too use full http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
It Contains whole command line arguments documentation

Thanx @Damien_The_Unbeliever for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working 2 days ago, and you didn't change any thing to your code, so look arround permissions, may be someone for some reasons changes the permissions on the server.

Other ways, if some changes occured on the code of (the asp.net application or on the .exe), start by going a step back (cancel last changes), and try again if it works, and if so, then look deeply in your changes, the problem is somewhere there.

Becarefull about the timeout of your process, it should not exceed the http request timeout (set by default to 20 sec).

Comment: no change in Asp.Net application, and no change in solution (which compiles each time). Permission, i have checked them, i did'nt found any thing, and on blogs that they said about permission, i have done all stuff, but not working of them

Comment: i have set in web.config, time out is set to one day

Comment: Well, you know, Microsoft send frequently new updates for there OS and all there applications like visual studio. may be one of those updates broke some thing in your applications (not compatible).

Comment: then what do you suggest, what should be my next step to resolve this problem

Comment: Try to uninstall the newest updates. but before that, Rotem made a suggestion in the first comment, your application name has may be spaces, and than you should put your argument between double qotes (like arguments = "\"D:\\ProjFolder\\xxx.sln \" /rebuild")

Comment: no, there is no space in path, although i am going to try your suggestion to put quotation in it

Comment: do you have any exception message?!!

Comment: no there was no exception, now i am using msbuild.exe instead of devenv.exe, and it is working well